# Installing Oracle 11g on debian

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, debian

I am trying to install Oracle 11g express edition on debian.

I downloaded it and unpackage.

I use alien -i --scripts on the folder.

And now i can access to the files and other folders.

The problem is when I try to do the next command  **configure etc/init.d/oracle-xe** it says "command not found".

I'm stuck with this.

Sorry if there are some mistakes in the writing I'm from Spain

Comment: I am using this guide http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17781_01/install.112/e18802/toc.htm

Answer (score 2):

The documentation you linked to [says to do this](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17781_01/install.112/e18802/toc.htm#CIHHJEHF):

```
/etc/init.d/oracle-xe configure
```

... not the way you have it, as `configure etc/...`. The `configure` is an argument to the `oracle-xe` command, not a command itself; and you need the leading `/` on the path before `etc`.

You might find [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/262106) and the links in it useful.

Comment: I tried that too but it doesn't work I'll the link it might be helpful

Answer (score 0):

It's the way @Alex Poole said, according to the 11gR2 Installation Guide.  As the error is "*Command not found*", check that the `/etc/init.d/oracle-xe` file actually exists.

```
ls -l /etc/init.d/oracle-xe
```

Don't forget to post the output, as it may bring context to this problem.